# Azure - Adding a User to the Master Table

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I just purchased a subscription to Azure, created a DB and now want to create a user login for a developer. All the documentation I've read on the net says that I must add the User to the 'Master Table' first before I can add the user to a specific DB. The question is, "where is it?". I have the latest version of visual studio and can see my DB, but can't see the Master Table.

Comment: When you say a "user login for a developer" do you mean a developer in your team who would work on your product?

Comment: Yes. Ultimately there will be three users. Myself (Admin - already created as part of the Azure subscription), a developer (whom I only want to have access to a single DB, not the entire Azure platform) and eventually, a third general login for users of a web app that the developer is building. To be clear, the developer does not need access to the Azure platform, but to be able to 'see' the DB in his version of Visual Studio and make changes to tables, run scripts and build stored procedures on the DB.

Comment: Found a piece of software (no, this is not a plug, found the reference on another post in this forum..) called AUMC that did the job perfectly! I've been searching for days for a solution and this is it. Hope it helps someone else.